# Can't open CloudSQL binlog: "No such file or directory"

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to view the MySQL binlog files to trace down the source of a particular query.  I used the SHOW BINARY LOGS query to get the names of the existing log files, but when trying to access using the mysqlbinlog command, I keep getting an error: "File 'xxxx' not found (Errocode: 2 "No such file or directory")".
I also tried accessing the file using the full path /mysql/binlog/mysql-bin/file-name and with double forward slashes and back slashes, but just got the same error.  I tried a couple of different files, all gave the same error.

If anyone can explain what I am doing wrong, that would be appreciated.

[image: No such file or directory error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqlbinlog utility checks your local file system, in this case. For remote server connection, you should use the --read-from-remote-server option in your command line. You can read related detail on the "4.6.8 mysqlbinlog — Utility for Processing Binary Log Files" [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html).